# Api-Platform: Filter Normalization Context Groups

Tags: php, rest, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

Hello guys I just started using Api-Platform and I got stuck on this problem for several hours.

I have a Symfony4 Project and two Entities: Bill & Abo

**Bill:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BillRepository")
 * @ApiResource(attributes={
 *   "normalization_context"={"groups"={"bill-abo"}}
 * })
 */
class Bill {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date", nullable=false)
     * @Groups("bill-abo")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Abo", inversedBy="bills")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn
     * @ApiSubresource
     * @Groups("bill-abo")
     */
    private $abo;
}
```

**Abo:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AboRepository")
 * @ApiResource
 */
class Abo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Groups("bill-abo")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Bill", mappedBy="abo")
     */
    private $bills;
}
```

When I now call this url, `/api/bills`, I get back this data:

```
{
  "date": "2018-03-14T00:00:00+00:00",
  "abo": {
    "price": 960
  }
},
...
```

My goal now is to call an url, something like this: `/api/bills?abo` to get the result above and when I call `/api/bills` I only want the bill data (without the abo data), like this:

```
{
  "id": 14,
  "date": "2018-03-08T00:00:00+00:00",
  "abo": "/api/abos/1"
},
...
```

I read the docs and specifically the parts about the [Group Filter](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#group-filter) and the [Property Filter](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#property-filter) but I coulnd't figure out a solution.

Is this even possible and if yes how can I achieve this?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the Group Filter.

1. Add the GroupFilter on the `Bill` resource class like this `@ApiFilter(GroupFilter::class, arguments={"overrideDefaultGroups": true, "whitelist": {"foo"}})`
2. Add an new extra group called "foo" to the `Bill::$abo` property (**don't** add to any property in the `Abo` class)
3. Try `/bills?groups[]=foo`

Comment: Thanks Kévin, but shouldn't the URI be like this, `/bills?groups[]=foo`?

Comment: I works with your filter but now I have to use `/api/bills?groups[]=foo` to get all bills without the abo data, but my goal is to use that to get the bills including the abo data. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, just invert:

1. `"normalization_context"={"groups"={"foo"}}` (remove `bill-abo`)
2. /api/bills?groups[]=bill-abo

Comment: I don't think you understand what I want to achieve or I don't get it =), maybe I was a bit unclear.

- When I call `/api/bills` I only want the bill data (without any abo data serialized)
- When I call `/api/bills?groups[]=foo` I want the bill data and the Subresource 
  data of the abo

Comment: So create a new group, don't add it to `abo`, and make it the default one.